# MySQL - JSON_CONTAINS not working on array with quotes or comma separated string?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a table with a json column in which I'm storing a list of ids for contract types. I want to do a join on the `contract_types` table so that I can get a concatenated list of contract type names for their ids.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_alerts` (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `criteria` JSON NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `contract_types` (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO contract_types (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Full time');
INSERT INTO contract_types (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Part time');

INSERT INTO my_alerts (id, name, criteria) VALUES (1, 'test', '{"contractTypes": ["1", "2"]}');
```

I try the following query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
   a.id, 
   a.name, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ', ') as contractTypes
FROM my_alerts a
LEFT JOIN contract_types c on JSON_CONTAINS(a.criteria, CAST(c.id as JSON), '$.contractTypes')
group by a.id
```

I can only get the query to work if I change the json column and store the array values without quotes:

```
{"contractTypes": [1, 2]}
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to change the way the array values are stored i.e. without quotes.

How can I get the above json_contains query to work when the json array values are stored in the following two formats:

```
{"contractTypes": ["1", "2"]}
```

or

```
{"contractTypes": ["1,2"]}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I've figured out how I can join if json is in the second format i.e. a comma separated list as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN contract_types c on find_in_set(c.id, JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.contractTypes'))
```

Now I only need some help with joining when array values have double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out this issue.

If your json column called 'user_ids' and it has the values like below:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

You can do this

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(user_ids, '"2"', '$') as u;
```

The 'u' will return 1.

The key for this solution is that you make sure wrap the number with those double quotes first and then the single quotes around it.

Comment: I ran into this problem today, and your solution solved it. I've seen a lot of ridiculous things in my 20+ years programming, and this definitely shows up toward the top of the list. But to be fair, I have a bad memory, so I've probably forgotten some other bad offenders

Answer (score 0):

Try and adjust what you need:

```sql
mysql> SELECT
    ->   CAST(JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(`id` SEPARATOR ', ')) AS JSON)
    -> FROM `contract_types`;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(`id` SEPARATOR ', ')) AS JSON) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["1, 2"]                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   CAST(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(CAST(`id` AS CHAR))), '],[', ', ') AS JSON)
    -> FROM `contract_types`;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(CAST(`id` AS CHAR))), '],[', ', ') AS JSON) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["1", "2"]                                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```